# JQuery Progress Image on Data Load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Quit new to jquery.

I've a web application which loads lots of data. Problem is that it takes 2 minute to load the the data on show on Graph.

If possible, I would like to show the progress bar as shown below:
http://ajaxload.info/

When data is loaded successfully I would like to stop and load the chart. Also, on button click the request is made to server and reloads another set of data based on button click. While it's loading data would like to show the same progress circle.

I'm using  $.ajax to make a server request.

If someone could please help will be much appreciated.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#loading-image').show();
$.ajax({
      url: uri,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
        $('.info').append(html);
      },
      complete: function(){
        $('#loading-image').hide();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a technique where the div that will hold the data will contain the rolling image by default and I make a jquery load function that will replace the result of the load function inside the div that hold the rolling image and this way the rolling image disappear when the data is loaded.